# How many gallons of water can you boil with one isobutane cannister?

Tags: camping, stoves

I'm trying to figure out how many cannisters of isobutane to bring on a 5 day family backpacking trip.

I figure we'll boil about 1.5 gallons of water per day (use this as a unit of measurement: gallon of water to boil).

So, to simplify: Let's assume 8 oz of isobutane (or whatever unite you want to use)

Comment: it is usually indicated in the manual of the stove

Comment: Eh, what's the temperature outside?

Answer (score 6):

1 oz of isobutane will boil about 1.8 L (about .475 gallons) of water, for a [Whisperliite Universal Stove](http://www.cascadedesigns.com/msr/blog/stoves-101-how-much-fuel-should-i-carry/)
[image]

Comment: Don't forget to factor in altitude as well if you are in the mountains.

Comment: @timbo water boils at lower temperature in higher altitudes, so not factoring _that_ in would not result in any problems, since you can boil even more water - at a lower temperature. I wonder however if isobutane might burn faster for the same reason, and how available oxygen, or the lack of it, might influence the burning speed.

Comment: My anecdotal experience is that it takes longer to boil at higher elevations. However, there are many factors which contribute... available oxygen, often colder water, etc. I think a major factor may be that the pressure of the gas inside the canister will be lower relative to the ambient atmosphere at higher elevation, meaning you'll get a lower gas flowrate.